# More than one java class in the same file

Tags: java

I am having trouble with some java code:

I created a class named clsEnum, and I want it to contain not just one class.

```
enum EnumDocument
{
    DNI(1), RUC(5), Grupo(7),Sucursal(8);

    private int value;

    EnumDocument(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }
}

enum EnumTypeRoleCredential
{
    Employee(81), Client(82), Supplier(83);
    private int value;

    EnumTypeRoleCredential(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Yes I know, I forgot to put the main class(clsEnum), but in this case I dont want to put it. This is the way I want it to work. So, when a I create an enumDocument object or a EnumTypeRoleCredential object, in a class wich is in the same package, I dont have any problem, but when I create an object in another class wich is in another package, the IDE(Eclipse juno) suggest to use "public", but when y use it, i get an error that says that the class needs its own file.

I use to do this en Visual Studio c#.net. Can it be done in Java, or i have to put necessary the subclasses into the main class.

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you try it out and see if it compiles

Comment: "This is the way I want it to work" - unfortunately for you, Java doesn't want to work that way. Based on your description, it seems that you're misusing nested classes to do what packages already give you.

Comment: You can enclose those in a public class named clsEnum, and place those two classes of Objects as public static.

Comment: I think @user1568613 is mixing up terms.  He didn't create a class called "clsEnum", he created a file called "clsEnum".  Also, he doesn't want it to contain two classes, he wants it to contain two Enums. Not that I think this changes the answers, but I think it helps others like myself who had to read it several times.  And hopefully this helps user1568613, too.

Comment: thanks everyone, now I am sure that this cant be donde in java. And @kurtzbot, this is exactly what i wanted, and as you said, this helped everyone =)

Answer (score 3):

- In a single Java file, you can have `at most` one `public class`, and if it is present, then the name of your java file should be the same as your `public class` name..

So, you can make only one of your `enums` public, and your file name should be the name of that `public enum` with `.java` extension..

- And your `public static void main` will also go into that `public class`
- And also, **this is important - If in a file you have `enums`, `classes` and `interfaces` all of them, then also only one of them would be `public`.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can have at most one `public` class (file name must match this class name) and arbitrary number of non-public classes. `public` class can be used everywhere once imported. non-public classes can be used only in the same package.

These are the rules, there's nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

In single java file you can have multiple no of classes but there could be only one public class and name of public class should as same as name of name of your file. That public class can be use anywhere